# How do I get a div to fit to the screen with no overflow in CSS

Tags: html, css, web

```
#topnavbar {
            width:100%;
            padding:0;
            border:1px solid gray;
            margin:0; }

        #topnavbar p {
            margin:0; }

        body {
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
            margin-top:0;
            width:1024px; }
```

That is my code. How do I get it to have the bar(which is named topnavbar) to fit the whole screen without overflowing? And I don't want to do `overflow:hide;` or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your css is a little off:

```
#topnavbar {
   width:100%;
   padding:0;
   border:1px solid gray;
   margin:0; 
}

#topnavbar p {
   margin:0; 
}

#container{
    width:1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

body {
   /* you do not need any of your css here */
}
```

html:

```
<body>
    <div id="topnavbar">
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        whatever you want to center
    </div>
</body>
```

the basic idea is to width 100% an element who does not have a parent and then apply your centering container beneath it. In this case, #container.

Your css was applying a width to the body and therefore it was likely messing up your whole layout.

Comment: i was replying to your comment, but you deleted a bit too quickly. I was saying: you're right, i was a bit too quick. But the border generated a horizontal scroll, hence his question about the overflow... I guess the answer is a bit the combination of both our answers :-)

Comment: indeed. funny though cause as I look back on it, it is possible he deliberately sized it to 1024 and was wondering about the scrollbar for the 2 pixels added by the border... only Marcus Szanto knows for sure at this point.

Comment: though he's still pondering in silence.

Answer (score 1):

You mean fit the whole width of the screen?

Paradoxally, you just need to remove `width:100%`(the borders are being added to this value...)

EDIT: And yes, Kai Qing is right, too - I missed that. If you put width 1024 on your body, your navbar will be 1024, too...

Comment: Yes. To clarify: width:100% means the *text-area* (which does not include border) of the div is 100% the width of its container, which in this case is the body (and since your page's body's width is unspecified, it means the viewport). If you remove width:100%, the topnav div's width with default to 'auto', which means it will stretch to fit its container precisely, taking into account border and padding.